# Geoserver linestring fill based on attribute value

Tags: geoserver, linestring, color, css, geoserver-css-module

I'm experimenting with Geoserver. I'm styling a linestring layer with CSS in this way, which works fine:

```
[userid = 1]  {

stroke: #8C2300;
stroke-width: 3px;
stroke-linecap: round;
z-index: 0, 1;

}
```

In my data store I have an attribute 'color' with hexadecimal values. Can I use this value for stroke color, in this way:

```
[userid = 1]  {

stroke: [color];
stroke-width: 3px;
stroke-linecap: round;
z-index: 0, 1;

}
```

Comment: Why the z-index: 0,1 if you have no second set of symbolizers in the properties?

Comment: What error do you get with the second one?

Answer (score 2):

You can, I would suggest removing the brackets from the [color] with the code as below;

```
[userid = 1]  {

stroke: color;  
stroke-width: 3px;  
stroke-linecap: round;  
z-index: 0, 1;  

}
```

This [tutorial](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/pretty_maps/css.html) provides a similar code block

Comment: Hi wyzar, thanks for your reply. When I do this, linestrings are styled in a default black color... I'm using sql server as datasource, and there is a string column 'color' with hexadecimal values (e.g. #661A00).

Comment: HI, have you got any solution this.